# How to view the webpage in Django tutorial on Linode server

Tags: django, linode

I know I have similar question with this post: [Django tutorial on remote server: how to view in my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097955/django-tutorial-on-remote-server-how-to-view-in-my-browser) But I just can't solve it with the answer it has.

I am playing with Django framework now. I am trying to do the Django tutorial on my Linode server. Everything works fine, but when we have to examine the webpage we have, the tutorial says that we have to check  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` on the server. I only have command line access on the Linode server, so I don't know how to see that webpage on the linode from my desktop. I tried to use the command like `python manage.py runserver 123.123.123.123:8000` and set the ip to my Linode server, but I still can't access that webpage from my desktop (I do remove the firewall for 8000 port). Does anyone know how can I check the change for the remote webpage I created within Django framework on the Linode server? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, are you trying to access the following URL in your browser (where the server ip address is 123.123.123.123)?

```
http://123.123.123.123:8000
```

Secondly, are you able to telnet to port 8000, to make sure you have correctly opened the port on the firewall.

Comment: For the first question, yes. For the second question, actually I have not tired yet. Maybe I should try now

Comment: I tried, I can't ping 123.123.123.123:8000, it says unknown host. I modified /etc/iptables.firewall.rules on my linode server (I put more allowance in this file), do I have to do anything to make this modification work? Or it will just work?

Comment: It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.

It worked after I reboot my machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I wanted to clarify what I did for others who might get stuck: 

First, remove the firewall for port 8000

```
sudo nano /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

Second, reboot the linode 
Third, restart the development server

```
cd /home/mycode/mysite
python manage.py runserver 123.123.123.123:8000
```

(where you use your ip)

Comment: Remember, it is not recommended to allow access to the development server or run a site publicly with debug=True. Think carefully before you open up port 8000 to the world.